# little javascript syntax help needed (short question)

Tags: javascript, html

I have an external js file which I am creating a tag in.

Problem is I don't know how to use the quotes if I am to add an onclick event to the code below.

Now this code works:

```
banner_div.innerHTML = '<a href=\"'+links[counter]+'\"><img src=\"'+images[counter]+'\" border=\"1px\" style=\"border-color:#000;\" alt=\"'+alts[counter]+'\" title=\"'+titles[counter]+'\"></a>';
```

But I need to add this to the above:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link Clicks', 'From Index.html', 'www.domain.com']);"
```

How should I insert the onclick event to the first piece of code so it works?

Thanks

BTW: The arrays above are iterated inside a for loop. So for example links[counter] contains the current index of the links array, which could be for example "www.somedomain.com".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem with using single quotes inside a single-quote delimited string. Remember, the whole onclick= thing is inside the large string surrounded by single quotes. So just backslash-escape the single quotes:

```
onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Link Clicks\', \'From Index.html\', \'www.domain.com\']);"
```

I would avoid using innerHTML, especially if you have a lot of substitutions. Too much can go wrong. For example, what if alts[counter] has some special HTML characters such as `&`? I would use the DOM to manipulate the object instead. For example

```
a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = links[counter];
a.setAttribute("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link Clicks', 'From Index.html', 'www.domain.com']);")
img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = images[counter];
img.border = "1px";
img.style = "border-color:#000;";
img.alt = alts[counter];
img.title = titles[counter];
a.appendChild(img);
banner_div.appendChild(a);
```

Though I guessed that without testing it, so it might be a bit wrong.

Note that I used short-hand property notation to assign all the attributes, but I used `setAttribute` to assign `onclick` because I tried using the property notation and it didn't work for me (the [DOM HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html) specification allows you to set most properties directly, but not `onclick`).

Comment: +1, good answer. That last part isn't quite right, though - some browsers will allow you to assign a string to `onclick` but as a general rule you should assign a function, e.g. `a.onclick = function () { _gaq.push([..., ...]); };`.

Comment: @Andy E: Can you find a specification for assigning a function object to a property like that? The DOM HTML spec doesn't mention those properties (it gives a list of special HTML attributes which may be referenced as properties instead of using `setAttribute`). The HTML4 spec (under Scripts) merely mentions that `onclick` and the like are attributes which take strings containing the script.

I haven't tried the two approaches in many different browsers, but from a reading of the specs, it seems like `setAttribute` is definitely standardised, whereas the other approach I can't find a reference.

Comment: @mguica: I don't think there was a solid definition until HTML5, which specifies that event handlers are exposed as IDL attributes (interface properties) and may also be exposed as content attributes.  IDL attributes expect a `Function` object, content attributes expect a valid `FunctionBody` representation. You can read more about [it here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers).  There are many interoperable features of browsers that are only just reaching a formal definition in the specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape double-quotes in a single-quoted string (and vice versa), so first we can simplify this quite a lot by just alternating quote-type appropriately:

```
banner_div.innerHTML = '<a onclick="' + "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Link Clicks', 'From Index.html', 'www.domain.com']);" + '" href="' + links[counter] + '"><img src="' + images[counter] + '" border="1px" style="border-color:#000;" alt="' + alts[counter] + '" title="' + titles[counter] + '"></a>';
```

In my opinion, this is a simpler solution than doing the DOM-manipulation in the accepted answer. We don't have to escape a single thing and we're not using a single function except good old string concatenation.

Why do we have two kinds of quotes? In order to make scenarios with lots of quotes (like this) simple!